# What is $options in vue and when to use it

Tags: vue.js

Could you explain what is $options and when to use it in vue. I've never used it and can't understand in docs. Show me please some code

Comment: We wrote a mixin that is getting added to a lot of components. We needed to get the name of component in mixin. We used 'this.$options.name' in the mixin to get the component name.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options

Answer (score 2):

$option is used for non reactive data in a vue component. Vue put hidden watcher on data members that's why we use $options .